# Does The Hulk's anger have a limit?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk

I have often heard that the Hulk can beat anyone because the more he fights, the angrier he'll get and he'll just keep getting stronger and stronger forever because of this.

However, I want to know if this is actually true. Are there any comics that show evidence  of whether or not the Hulk's anger (and therefore his strength) have a limit?

Comment: There's a good answer here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60445/is-there-an-upper-limit-to-the-hulk-s-strength although that question was closed as POB because of the way it's worded

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the comic [*Secret Wars II*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_Wars_II), [the Beyonder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyonder) analyzed the Hulk's physiology and claimed that the Hulk's potential strength had "no finite element inside." This would seem to imply that there is no limit to how strong the Hulk can get, a by product of which meaning that there is no limit to how angry the Hulk can get, as Hulk's strength scales up with how angry he is.

For reference, the angriest we have ever seen the Hulk is in the [*World War Hulk*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_Hulk) story-line, in which Hulk, furious with the [Illuminati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illuminati_%28comics%29) after the destruction of his planet and the death of his family, travels back to Earth in order to extract vengeance. In it, Hulk defeats several of the most powerful characters that Marvel have ever created, including [Black Bolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Bolt) and [Doctor Strange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Strange), and even goes toe to toe with [Sentry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentry_%28Robert_Reynolds%29).

Comment: However, in *World War Hulk* he'd gotten *so* angry he'd entered passed rage and gone into Tranquil Fury, so he actually appeared calm. Which made it worse, because not only was his strength at peak levels, but he was able to coldly analyze his enemies.

Comment: Worth noting that in the descriptions of his arrival back on Earth in World War Hulk, he is described as being capable of splitting the planet with just the force of his footsteps should he so desire.

Comment: I would say he actually BEAT Sentry. After the fight, Sentry was done... he was out for the count. Bruce could've hulked out again, but chose not to.